# PowerShell: Console Warning from Rename-Computer into a Var

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to capture the Console warning that is outputted after running the Rename-Computer command. I'd tried to tie bits and piece from other Stack Overflow threads on output redirection, but I can't seem to get it to work.

What I'm trying to do is rename a remote computer into a variable.  After the command successfully completes, take the warning "WARNING: The changes will take..." and have its string placed in the variable.

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName $deviceName -ScriptBlock{param($name); Rename-Computer $name -DomainCredential (Get-Credential) | Out-String -InputObject $output ;Return $output} -ArgumentList $newDeviceName`

I have tried the Invoke-Command inside a var and out to see if that changes anything. The reason I want the console message placed into the variable and not do redirection to a file is because I'm messing around with WPF GUI and want the warning printed to my GUI window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the output from `Rename-Computer` is going to the **Warning stream**, this is how you can capture it:

```
$output = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $deviceName -ScriptBlock{
    param($name)
    Rename-Computer $name -DomainCredential (Get-Credential) 3>&1
} -ArgumentList $newDeviceName

$output # => Should be the warning from Rename-Computer
```

Here is a simple example:

```
$capture = Write-Warning 'Hello World!'      # doesn't work!
$capture = Write-Warning 'Hello World!' 3>&1 # works!
```

For more information, see [about_Output Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.2) and [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2).

Comment: You nailed it, thanks a lot.  I admittedly skimmed output streams.  Obviously failed to grasp how it applies to my issue.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @nwood happy to help, don't worry about it, powershell streams can be a bit confusing at the beginning :)